# ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined working on vanilla js

Tags: javascript, async-await, contentful

```
    const client = contentful.createClient({
     space: "some random generated id",
     accessToken: "some random generated token"
     });

    const getProducts = async() => {
      let contentful = await client.getEntries()
        content_type: 'houseproducts'
        console.log(contentful.items);
     }
     getProducts()
```

this code use to work very fine before but now it throws error in some devices in which it used to work very fine without any error.
here iam fetching api from contentful and throws this error:-

```
contentful.browser.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) 
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
at Object.O (contentful.browser.min.js:1)
at Object.getEntries (contentful.browser.min.js:1)
at getProducts (trial.js:9)
at trial.js:13
```

here contenttype is the the name of the project in created in contentful